# django ModelForm: the form in the html cannot enter data and submit

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I created a Model Form, but in the page, it can only display the form, but cannot enter the data and no response after clicking the "submit" button. Is there anything wrong in my views or template?

There iis no error alert when I open the page.

Thanks for your help.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'

     # /URL-to-ajax-view/
    def ajax_get_queryset(request):
        if self.request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:

            form = InputForm(self.request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                company = form.cleaned_data['company']
                region = form.cleaned_data['region']

                queryset=Result.objects.filter(company=company,region=region)
                sales=Result.objects.queryset.aggregate(Sum('sales'))

            return render(request, 'dupont', {'sales': sales,'region':region,'queryset': queryset})
    else:
        form=InputForm()
```

**result_list.html**

```
<style type="text/css">

.basicinfo {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 115px;
left: 22px;
top: 0px;   
}

<body>
<div class="basicinfo">
<form id="InputForm" method="post" action="">   #here is the data entry form
        {% csrf_token %}

        <!--enter the company name--> 
        <div class="field">
            {{ form.company.errors }}
            <label id="id_company" name="company" for="{{ form.company.id_for_label }}">Company:</label>
            {{ form.company }}
        </div>

        <!--select region-->
        <div class="field" >
            <label> Select the Region:
            {{ form.region }}
                {% for region in form.region.choices %}
                     <option value="region" name= "region" id="id_region">{{region}} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </label>
        </div>

        <!--submit-->
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p></div>
    </form> 
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#InputForm").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    var region= $("#id_region").val();
    var company= $("#id_company").val();

        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('post'),
            url: "dupont_list/",
            success: function(data) { // on success..
                $("#result").html(data); // update the DIV "result"
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>


    <div id="result" class="result">   <!--Showing the filtered result in database-->

    <table>
    <tr><b>Sales</b></tr>
    <td> {{sales.sales__sum}}</td>


    <tr><b>Employee</b></tr>
    <td> {{employee.employee__sum}}</td>
    </table>
```

Comment: change input type  submit to "button"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is being shadowed by an absolutely positioned element in your html.
try adding this to your css:

```
form{ position:absolute;z-index:100 }
```

This will lift your form above whatever is shadowing it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a small error in your code:

```
if self.request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:
```

should be

```
if self.request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
```

Note the **()**

Also: Change the button from submit to button.

Comment: Hi@Vingtoft,thank u a lot, but I suspect my code has more errors than that. I want to embed the Ajax Form Plugin: after submit the form, on the same html displays the filtered result based on user entry.